# Best way to programatically fill in a white border with a black border on images

Tags: image-processing, gdi

I have over 100k in images that at one time were cropped and had a white border applied to them.  I'm looking for the best way to programmaticly process each image so that I can detect the white borders and either crop the border or fill in the border with black instead.  Would I need to use something like OpenCV or just plain old GDI?  I've attached an image for reference.

What I have to work with (White borders are there, trust me):

http://cdn-images.hollywood.com/site/SO_3666231.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Plain old GDI should work just fine, except for one thing - I don't know how to make GDI save an image back to a file. When I've had to do it in the past I've written a .BMP file in pieces, which wouldn't work for a JPEG. Time for a new question?

You're going to need a two step process - first measure the white borders, then copy the image to a new image to get rid of them.

Starting with a JPEG image introduces two small problems. First is that the image will contain some decoding artifacts, and white won't always be an RGB value of (255,255,255). You'll need to establish a threshold, such as (250,250,250) and see how that works; if it doesn't catch all of the borders, you'll need to try a lower threshold. Second is that resaving the image as a JPEG will introduce additional artifacts, lowering the quality of the image. Hopefully this will be within acceptable limits, but only you can be the judge of that.

I'm sorry that this isn't really an answer, perhaps more like 1/4 of an answer. I hope you find it useful.